# Power BI data reload from Excel

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI, while creating a Power BI project,
each time I want to update the data by loading the same Excel workbook
with the same tables and the same columns with different cells values I
noticed that the power bi project file doesn't "recognize" the tables,
it forces me process the data all over again, I'm trying to create a
dashboard template which can be fed with new data without doing the
same data processing tasks each update...

Is there a way to refresh the data without losing queries and formulas ?
Maybe using an online MySql database instead excel can be a solution ?

Comment: Excel is not the problem. How exactly did you import the tables?

Comment: What do you mean by `it forces me process the data all over again`?

Answer (score 0):

So, From Power BI Ribbon->Get Data-> File->Folder (you should be placing all your excel source files in a folder and then that Particular folder will be acting as a source for your Power BI file). Please refer screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here your folder name will be your Table name in Power BI
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps !!

Comment: The thing is no one will update the excel
I will get a new file with the same columns, diffrent values. What can be done in such case ?

Comment: Does the file name remain the same?

Comment: No, the file is generated from other software. What are the conditions for the refresh to work ? Same file name ? Same path ? Anything else ?